# How can I delete the lines that contain a part (search word) in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, and I want delete all rows, which contains a part of a string (search keys).

my dataframe:

```
    user_name   user_first_name     user_email
    Max          Mustermann          max.musterman@gmail.com
    Tom          Hans                tom.musterman@web.de
    Tom1          Hans1              tom.musterman@test.de
```

my search keywords are: @gmail.com, @web.de

```
df = df[~df['user_email'].isin(['*@gmail.com'])]
```

It doesn't work, because I need to write the excat email adress.

Comment: I think it should be `'@gmail.com' in user_email` not `user_email in '@gmail.com'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.endswith`:

```py
df = df[~df['user_email'].str.endswith('@gmail.com')]

  user_name user_first_name             user_email
1       Tom            Hans   tom.musterman@web.de
2      Tom1           Hans1  tom.musterman@test.de
```

Or `str.contains` which supports regex:

```py
df = df[~df['user_email'].str.contains('.*@gmail\.com$')]

  user_name user_first_name             user_email
1       Tom            Hans   tom.musterman@web.de
2      Tom1           Hans1  tom.musterman@test.de
```

Your list implies that you might want to pass multiple conditions, so `str.contains` would probably be the best bet, using `|` to delimit conditions:

```py
df = df[~df['user_email'].str.contains('.*@gmail\.com$|.*@web\.de$')]

  user_name user_first_name             user_email
2      Tom1           Hans1  tom.musterman@test.de
```